# SSIS cannot deploy package to SQL server - An error occurred during decryption 15466

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssis, ssrs, visual-studio

After recovering and re-importing a backup of a SQL Server 2019 instance none of my SSIS packages will deploy from Visual Studio.

Whenever I try and deploy I get the error

```
===================================

An error occurred during decryption. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
Server Name: SSRS02\HEALTHAWARE
Error Number: 15466
Severity: 16
State: 9
Line Number: 1
```

I have tried to reimport the backup of the encryption key that I have through the Report Server Configuration Manager, and have run the following and have seen it succeed, so I am assuming that my master key is correct, and I have the correct decryption password for the master key.

```
OPEN Master KEY
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
ALTER Master KEY
    DROP ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
ALTER Master KEY
    ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
CLOSE MASTER KEY;
GO
```

I cannot however figure out what I need to do in order to get the SSIS Packages to deploy from Visual Studio

Comment: The encryption key set in Report Server Configuration Manager is specific to the SSRS application. It's wholly unrelated to SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have to encrypt it again using the ssisdb original password in this way:

```
open master key decryption by password = 'xxxxx' –‘Password used when creating SSISDB’
Alter Master Key Add encryption by Service Master Key
```